# Why does cloneNode need to be used when using <template/> with Shadow Dom

Tags: web-component, shadow-dom, clonenode, html-templates

I've been looking around the mdn documents about web component,I followed the link and i arrived to documents about template below the link is what i was looking.

### According to the documents

[image: mdn sceenshot]

> 

it says if i don't append node by using cloneNode? template's inner style will does not work. But i try both just append and append with cloneNode but both test was same.... So i have a question that am i miss understanding or spec changes to support both? i test both browser in chrome , safari

#### code with out cloneNode

```html
<template id="my-paragraph">
    <style>
      p {
        color: white;
        background-color: #666;
        padding: 5px;
      }
    </style>
    <p>My paragraph</p>
  </template>
<my-paragraph></my-paragraph>

<script>
  customElements.define('my-paragraph',
    class extends HTMLElement {
      constructor() {
        super();
        let template = document.getElementById('my-paragraph');
        let templateContent = template.content;
        const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({
          mode: 'open'
        })
        var style = document.createElement('style');
        style.textContent = `
p{
  font-size: 30px;
  color:'black';
}`;
        shadowRoot.appendChild(style)
        console.log(template)
        shadowRoot.appendChild(templateContent);
      }
    }
  );
</script>
```

#### code using cloneNode

```html
<template id="my-paragraph">
    <style>
      p {
        color: white;
        background-color: #666;
        padding: 5px;
      }
    </style>
    <p>My paragraph</p>
  </template>
<my-paragraph></my-paragraph>

<script>
  customElements.define('my-paragraph',
    class extends HTMLElement {
      constructor() {
        super();
        let template = document.getElementById('my-paragraph');
        let templateContent = template.content;
        const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({
          mode: 'open'
        })
        var style = document.createElement('style');
        style.textContent = `
p{
  font-size: 30px;
  color:'black';
}`;
        shadowRoot.appendChild(style)
        console.log(template)
        shadowRoot.appendChild(templateContent.cloneNode(true));
      }
    }
  );
</script>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_templates_and_slots

Answer (score 0):

`.content` **moves** the content,
`.content.cloneNode(true)` makes a **deep copy** of the `<template>`

See SO snippet below; the **3rd** `<my-paragraph>` can't get any content from the `<template>` because the **2nd** `<my-paragraph>` **moved** all of the template to its `<my-paragraph>` **shadowDOM**

```html
<template id="MY-PARAGRAPH">
    <style>
      p {
        background: lightgreen;
        padding: 5px;
      }
    </style>
    <p><slot></slot></p>
  </template>
<my-paragraph cloned>Cloned Content</my-paragraph>
<my-paragraph>Content only</my-paragraph>
<my-paragraph>Content only</my-paragraph>
<script>
  customElements.define('my-paragraph',
    class extends HTMLElement {
      constructor() {
        // yes you can place javascript BEFORE the super() call, the docs are wrong
        const template = () => {
          let content = document.getElementById(this.nodeName).content;
          if (content.children.length) {
            if (this.hasAttribute("cloned"))
              return content.cloneNode(true)
            else
              return content;
          } else {
            document.body.append(`content in template: `, this.nodeName);
          }
        }
        super() // sets AND returns this-Scope
          .attachShadow({mode: 'open'})  // sets AND returns this.shadowRoot
          .append(template()) // no need for appendChild if you don't use its return value
      }
    }
  );
</script>
```